# How do you write a Rails finder query for a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many, finder

I'm using Rails 5.  I have the following class

```
class ParentObject < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :child_objects, :optional => false
end
```

I have a parameter, `params[:child_objects]`, passed in to my controller that is an array of those objects' IDs.  How can I write a finder to return objects tied to those IDs?  I tried this

```
parent_objects = ParentObject.joins(:child_objects).where(
  :child_objects => child_objects
)
```

but got this error

```
Unknown primary key for table parent_objects_child_objects in model ParentObject::HABTM_ChildObjects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find these registers with this query bellow

```
ParentObject.joins(:child_objects).where('child_objects.id in (?)', child_objects)
```

> where('child_objects.id in (?)', child_objects) # you are searching ids into child_objects table. Specify the join table `child_objects.id`

This is the same query, but more RailsWay. Same idea

```
ParentObject.joins(:child_objects).where(child_objects: { id: child_objects} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the classes defined, `has_and_belongs_to_many` means a parent can have many children, as well as a child, can belong to many parents. This qualifies for a many to many relation and thus needs an associative (or junction) table.

For above-defined classes, rails will look for `child_objects_parent_objects` and raise error if table not present. Add a junction table as defined below

```rb
CREATE TABLE `child_objects_parent_objects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child_object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

And then the below query will return **parent objects** for the given child objects(`params[:child_objects]`).

```rb
ParentObject.joins(:child_objects).where(child_objects: { id: child_object_ids})
```

However, If you want a child to belong to only 1 parent then define a `has_many` relation & junction table will not be required.

```rb
class ParentObject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_objects
end

ParentObject.joins(:child_objects).where(child_objects: { id: child_object_ids})
```